# Restore Time Machine backup

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, time-machine, restore

I want to restore from my Time Machine backup.

My Time Machine backups where saved on a QNAP NAS. After a clean install (forgot password) of my MacBook, I wanted to reinstall from my Time Machine backups.  This was not possible because the file was corrupted. I couldn't fix it with Disk Utility nor CLI. Disk Warrior was able to fix the file (`xxx.backupbundle`).

When I now want to install from my Time Machine backup (295 GB), I can select the backup but it seems empty. The same thing happens when I try Migration Assistant.

On this Mac I am still running Catalina.

Is there a possibility to retrieve the files out of the (`xxx.backupbundle`) or is there any other solution to get my files back?

Answer (score 1):

After many attempts I was able to recover my files.

I mounted the .backupbundle, then I went to the folder .Trashes/501/... via the command line. Here were several folders per dates, in these folders I could find my files.